# Cast to int not working in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to store a time value in an array, but it gives me an error every time, even when I try to cast the float into an int. Here is the portion of my code:

```
EndTimes = [0,0,0,0]
...
EndTimes[TakenSlots] = int(time.time() + n)
```

But it just gives this error:

```
[error] TypeError ( list indices must be integers )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
44: main ( craftTime ) EndTimes[TakenSlots] = tempInt
```

I tried this code just to see what it thought the value was:

```
tempInt = int(time.time() + n)
print tempInt
EndTimes[TakenSlots] = tempInt
```

And it just outputted 1412046180 (no decimal places, which seems like it should be an int)

Does anyone know what's happening? Is it a problem with the int() or the type of array I'm using? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the list index ( list[index] = value ) must be an integer. It is probable that TakenSlots is not an int.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l[1.3] = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

Comment: Oops, you're totally right! I changed around my variables earlier and totally forgot. Thanks for the help!